# How to send data in tabular format fetched from data base in email using python?

Tags: python, html, database, jinja2

I am trying to send the fetched data in a tabular format. The output I am getting in my mail box is :

```
{% for row in {results} %}  {{row[0]}}  {{row[1]}}  {{row[2]}}  {{row[3]}}  {{row[4]}}  {% endfor %}
```

Here is the code:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib
import psycopg2
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'Table'
msg['From'] = "pathakgandharv@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "pathakgandharv@gmail.com"
text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the data you wanted :"
# DatabaseConncetion
user = "------"
password = "-----"
host = "@some host"
port = 8081
database = " "
insert_time="some value"
entity_name="some value"
db_conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=host, user=user, password=password, database=database)
cursor = db_conn.cursor()
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM operational_metadata WHERE bor_name = %s and insert_time  = %s;"
cursor.execute(sql_query, (entity_name, insert_time,))
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    a0=row[0]
    a1=row[1]
    a2=row[2]
    a3=row[3]
    a4=row[4]

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <table border="1">

     <tr>
     {% for row in {results} %}
        <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
     {% endfor %}

     </tr>

   </table>
  </body>
</html>
"""
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login("pathakgandharv@gmail.com","----------")
mail.sendmail("pathakgandharv@gmail.com","pathakgandharv@gmail.com", msg.as_string())
mail.quit()
```

How can I send the data in tabular format? I am able to fetch all the values from the database. Is there any other and better approach?
I tried using PrettyTable but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of problems with your code.

- You have only used Django template syntax but not rendered it (along with context) into proper HTML.
- Python's square braces syntax for accessing list elements will not work with Django's templates. Inside the template code, instead of `row[0]` use `row.0`.

Do the below changes to generate proper HTML for the mail body

```py
from django.template import Template, Context

...
...

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <table border="1">
     {% for row in results %}  <!-- braces are not required since `results` is a context variable -->
     <tr>
        {% for item in row %}
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}

   </table>
  </body>
</html>
"""

template = Template(html)
html = template.render(Context({'results': results})

...
...
```

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-variables to understand how the dot operator works inside Django templates.

Comment: That is not the problem

Comment: Thanks, man, more thing- I have for now two lists in results, But there can be many depending upon the user . So, I have no control over that. For instance, each list has 15 values. That is for sure fixed. I want to print data list wise ie 1st list should be in the first row, 2nd list should be in the second row and so on. I am not able to figure how to add each row dynamically for that scenario. Can you help me with that? Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: I have updated the answer to handle variable no. of rows and items.